# MS Access required field validation rule not working for the existing records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access table and form, there are already existing rows and I need to add more rows. For a column called `Status` with possible values "Yes" or "No", I created a required column and created a validation rule as "Yes" or "No".

It works on the new entries in the form but not on the existing rows. Can someone let me know how to make this work on the existing rows as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run an update (or delete) query to adjust (or remove) those entries.

Comment: one possibility is yes/no maps to -1 and 0 instead of 0,1  and the previous data was entered assuming 0,1 see here: https://superuser.com/questions/694919/why-do-yes-no-values-in-microsoft-access-map-to-1-and-0

Comment: @Gustav, I want to keep the exisitng records. Is there a vba program that works for existing and new entries?

Comment: Run two queries.